# Image sitemap. Image with multiple locations tags are valid?

Tags: image, syntax, sitemap

I have question ebout generatong image sitempap as described here: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178636

If i have some images that differ only in image size (they are scalled). Can I have multiple `<image:loc>` tags inside single `<image:image>`?

```
<image:image>
     <image:loc>http://example.com/image_size1.jpg</image:loc>
     <image:loc>http://example.com/image_size2.jpg</image:loc>
     <image:loc>http://example.com/image_size3.jpg</image:loc>
     <image:caption>Sample caption</image:caption>
</image:image>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a separate `<image:image> ... </image:image>` for each image. (So the answer to your question is "no")